# custom omniauth client- Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, omniauth, doorkeeper

trying to create a custom omniauth client to interact with api base rails app , the provider app is working perfectly with devise and doorkeeper integrated [ApiProvider app](https://github.com/shubhangisingh/api_provider)
on trying to authorize the client app using doorkeeper ui I am getting following error in console

```
I, [2017-01-17T15:37:31.760972 #13511]  INFO -- omniauth: (api_provider) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2017-01-17T15:37:31.767541 #13511] ERROR -- omniauth: (api_provider) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
E, [2017-01-17T15:37:31.767730 #13511] ERROR -- omniauth: (api_provider) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
```

[csrf_detected | CSRF detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f3Ub.png)

Comment: https://github.com/shubhangisingh/api_client  - source code

Comment: Looks like you are trying to make external requests and check for `authenticity_token` skip CSRF validation for oauth action with `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`, as it will be and external request, usually made on first interaction